# How to make absolute path to relative path so that dll can find its dependency in more than one computer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, java-native-interface

I've built a dll(we can name it as dll A) which uses third-party dll(dll B).My configuration of dll A is like below(the IDE is VS 2008):

1. Right click the project--->properties--->Configuration Properties--->C/C++--->General--->Additional Include Directories  (It's the directory of header file of dll B(**absolute path**))
2. Right click the project--->properties--->Configuration Properties--->Linker--->General--->Additional Library Directories  (It's the directory of lib which connects with dll B(**absolute path**))
3. Right click the project--->properties--->Configuration Properties--->Linker--->Input--->Additional Dependencies (It's the name of lib mentioned above)

The dll B is provided by third party.I know what I actually called is dll B and I can locate dll B by the lib(**Am I right?**).
I use dll A in a Java App by jni. It works normally in my computer but I have requirement to make the Java App to run on the other computer.What should I do to make it work?Can I change absolute path to relative path and how?

Comment: you can put B.dll and A.dll at the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put B.dll and A.dll at the same folder, so A.dll can find B.dll when you App load it.

Below are search path on windows to Locate a DLL.

1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
2. The current directory.
3. The Windows system directory. The GetSystemDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
4. The Windows directory. The GetWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
5. The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.